# Jquery clone limit

Tags: jquery, clone

I have this code:

```
$("#addbt").click(function () {
 $('#choice').clone()
     .attr('id', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
     .attr('name', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
     .insertAfter(".ddl:last"); });
```

I am new to Jquery. How can I stop the number of clones to a specific number? (say 10)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that while maintaining roughly the same code structure you currently have is to use a counter like so:

```
 counter = 0;
 $("#addbt").click(function () {
         counter++;
         if (counter <= 10){
            $('#choice').clone()
              .attr('id', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
              .attr('name', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
              .insertAfter(".ddl:last"); });
          }
  }
```

Comment: try putting together a jsfiddle demonstrating your code not working.